# My print prescription function is not working

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I want to print patient prescription details in using prescription button. My problem was prescription button is not working. The function is not working.

```
     <div id="prescription_print">

    table width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <TD align="left" valign="top">
                        <?php foreach ($patient_info as $row2){ ?>
                            <?php echo 'Patient Name: '.$row2['name']; ?><br>
                            <?php echo 'Age: '.$row2['age']; ?><br>
                            <?php echo 'Sex: '.$row2['sex']; ?><br>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top">
                        <?php $name = $this->db->get_where('doctor' , array('doctor_id' => $row['doctor_id'] ))->row()->name;
                              echo 'Doctor Name: '.$name;?><br>
                        <?php echo 'Date: '.date("d M, Y", $row['timestamp']); ?><br>
                        <?php echo 'Time: '.date("H:i", $row['timestamp']); ?><br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>         
        </div>

    <!-----------   prescription button------>
    <a onClick="PrintElem('#prescription_print')" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon icon-left hidden-print">
            Print Prescription
            <i class="entypo-doc-text"></i>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <!-----------   prescription function------>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function PrintElem(elem)
        {
            Popup($(elem).html());
        }

        function Popup(data)
        {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'prescription', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Prescription</title>');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/neon-theme.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/datatables/responsive/css/datatables.responsive.css"
type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();

            return true;
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: What does it mean exactly "it's not working"?

Comment: This is not the complete code. There is an `endforach;` without it's start. Do you have the same ID `#prescription_print` multiple times? an ID must be unique. Do you get any javascript errors in the console of your browser?

Comment: Also make sure your browser isn't blocking pop-up windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have written this line:

```
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/datatables/responsive/css/datatables.responsive.css"
type="text/css" />');
```

In two lines (the string contains a line break). This makes the JavaScript invalid, so your function isn't created.

Remove the line break and it works.

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/m11fmqhr/)